# URL Rewrite language querystring

Tags: iis-7, url-rewriting

I want to rewirte my querystring for selected language.

I have this URL: www.example.com/?lang=en, and want it to be www.example.com/en

It should rewrite on all pages. So www.example.com/contact.aspx?lang=en would be www.example.com/en/contact.aspx

Is there a general rewrite rule for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This one works.

```
<rule name="Rewrite Language">
    <match url="([a-z]{2})(.*)" />
    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Rewrite" url="{R:2}?lang={R:1}" />
</rule>
```

Answer (score 0):

my syntax may be a little off but you could probably do something like this:

```
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="Rewrite Language">
      <match url="/([a-z]+)/([_0-9a-z-]+)" />
      <action type="Rewrite" url="{R:2}?lang={R:1}" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```

Comment: That doesn't seem to work. Gives me 404 with example.com/en/contact.aspx

Comment: I haven't played with URL re-writting yet, but wouldn't the action tag's url need a leading '/' in front to match the leading '/' in the match tag's url?

Answer (score 0):

Please consider using the following:

```
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="Rewrite Language">
      <match url="/([a-z]{2})(.*)" />
      <action type="Rewrite" url="{R:2}?lang={R:1}" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```